# Screensaver in the Shell

Tags: cron, screensaver

I like the screensaver `cmatrix`. Is their a way to set up a `crontab` to check if the shell is inactive every 10 mins (using `xprintidle`) and then if that is true run the screensaver command `cmatrix -abs`?

Comment: Why the complication of `cron(8)` which is outside of X11 instead of using something like `xidle(1)` ?